# NetFlix API : "expand" not working with pyflix2

Tags: python, python-2.7, netflix

Netflix API says that this URL:

```
http://api-public.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/60036637?expand=synopsis%20cast%20directors%20awards%20similars
```

should work while getting title details. And this should expand all the links sent as the parameter "expand", i.e. synopsis, cast, director, awards and similars. However, in pyflix2 (a python implementation for accessing netflix API) when I do the same it doesn't work.

The code I am using is like below:

```
import pyflix2

netflix = pyflix2.NetflixAPIV2( 'App_ID', 'APP_KEY', 'SHARED_SECRET')
movieDetails = netflix.get_title(title["id"], "synopsis cast directors awards similars")
```

The get_title() function is written as follows in the pyflix2 lib (I had tweaked it to get the required functionality):

```
def get_title(self, id,  category=None):
    if id.startswith('http'):
        url=id

        url="%s?expand=%s" %(url,urllib.quote(category))

        return self._request('get', url).json()
    else:
        raise NetflixError("The id should be like: http://api.netflix.com/catalog/movies/60000870")
```

This still returns me collapsed links which I would have got with this query:

http://api-public.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/60036637

I feel somewhere the parameter I am attaching is getting malformed and is being omitted. I have tried the same URL on this link :

http://kentbrewster.com/netflix-api-explorer/

And it gives me the correct response. Maybe, pyflix2 is going wrong somewhere. Has anyone worked on the same and faced this issue? Please respond ASAP.

Comment: Please define what "doesn't work" *means*. Exception? Then give us the traceback. No results or results not matching expectations? Then tell us what you expected and what you got instead.

Comment: Hi Martijn... "doesn't work" means I don't get any expanded links. All I get is normal result which I would have got even without the "expand" parameter added to the GET request. Sorry for the confusion, I hope it is clear to you now.

Comment: You can [edit] your question. I don't know anything about the NetFlix API myself, just trying to help you improve your question to increase the chances of it getting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing space separated list of expand topics. It should be a comma separated list. Also for V2 api the expands look like `@synopsis`, `@cast` etc.

The uri in case of V2 should look like: http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/493387?expand=@cast,@synopsis&v=2.0

```
def get_title(self, id,  category=None):
    if id.startswith('http'):
        url=id
        data["expand"] = ",".join(category)
        return self._request('get', url, data).json()
    else:
        raise NetflixError("The id should be like: http://api.netflix.com/catalog/movies/60000870")`
```

(I have removed all error checks in the above code, for clarity)

Call this as:

```
movieDetails = netflix.get_title(title["id"], ["@synopsis", "@cast", "@directors", "@awards", "@similars"]);
```

Comment: Just to add to Arup's answer, `@synopsis, @cast` etc. also applies to v=1.5.  And for the default (v1.0) you would call it like so `expand=cast,similars,synopsis` etc